# How do I access custom fields in an error?

Tags: go, dropbox-sdk

## Objective

Add a command to dropbox's CLI tool to get the shared link for the given path (file or folder).

The changes are here: [github fork](https://github.com/jondb/dbxcli/blob/jondb/create-shared-link/cmd/share-create.go).

## Background

The dropbox-go-sdk has a function that takes a path, and returns a new shared link, or returns an error containing the existing shared link.

I don't know how to use the error to extract the existing shared link.

## Code

[on github](https://github.com/jondb/dbxcli/blob/jondb/create-shared-link/cmd/share-create.go), and snippet here:

```golang
    dbx := sharing.New(config)
    res, err := dbx.CreateSharedLinkWithSettings(arg)
    if err != nil {
        switch e := err.(type) {
        case sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAPIError:
            fmt.Printf("%v", e.EndpointError)
        default:
            return err
        }
    }
```

This prints the following:

```
&{{shared_link_already_exists} <nil> <nil>}found unknown shared link typeError: shared_link_already_exists/...
```

tracing:
[CreateSharedLinkWithSettings](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/client.go#L687) --> [CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAPIError](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/client.go#L682) --> [CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsError](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/types.go#L593) --> [SharedLinkAlreadyExistsMetadata](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/types.go#L3861) --> IsSharedLinkMetadata

`IsSharedLinkMetadata` contains the Url that I'm looking for.

## More Info

- The API docs point to [CreateSharedLinkWithSettings](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/client.go#L687), which should pass [back the information in the error](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-go-unofficial/blob/2f186d1020b6b6901eacb0b6b82c7fc676fd5995/dropbox/sharing/client.go#L738) including the existing Url.

I struggle to understand how to deal with the error and extract the url from it.

- The dbxcli has [some code](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli/blob/a871c88e22f4575d2f2cb1b77af9a91975acd296/cmd/ls.go#L69) doing a similar operation, but again, not sure how it's working enough to apply it to the code I'm working on. Is it a Struct? Map? I don't know what this thing is called. There's some weird magic `err.(type)` stuff happening in the code. How do I access the data?

Comment: See ["Type Assertions"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), and ["Type Switches"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) in the docs. You may want to start with the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to get a quick grasp of the basics.

Comment: k - this helps me grok why the switch statement works with the err.(type). How do I access the new things on the err variable?

Comment: You access it exactly like in the example you linked. The value assigned in the type switch (or type assertion) is of the type you are looking for.

Comment: why does the code put e := err.(type) in the switch, then access `e` instead of `err` in the code? Reading it, `e` is the type, not the value.

Comment: `e` is not the type, `e` is a value of that type. It's the same as a type assertion. Look at the example in the "type switch" documentation I linked, which shows exactly what the assigned value types are in which cases.

Comment: `e == err` - is there something else happening, or can i just use err in the case?

Comment: i'm stuck here: `fmt.Printf("%v", e.EndpointError.Path)` -> This prints 'nil' and `fmt.Printf("%v", e.EndpointError.SharedLinkAlreadyExists)` is a compile error `e.EndpointError.SharedLinkAlreadyExists undefined (type *sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsError has no field or method SharedLinkAlreadyExists)`

Comment: If you're not sure what you are working with, use `"%#v"` to quickly see the types and field names too.

Comment: thanks - that's a great trick.... looks like the version of the db-go-sdk that dbxcli uses doesn't define what i'm looking for.

Comment: last question - is the err object a 'struct' or an 'interface'? and isn't an 'interface' basically a class definition, and an implementation a class instance? Or are we not calling them classes because they don't inherit?

Comment: `error` is an interface. There are no classes, because there there is no inheritance and hence to reason to call something as a "class" for class based inheritance.

Comment: There is just one sensible approach: Learn how interfaces and type assertions and type switches work. Do the Tour of  Go.

Comment: @JimB - if you could answer the question i can award you the accepted answer. Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
dbx := sharing.New(config)
    res, err := dbx.CreateSharedLinkWithSettings(arg)
    if err != nil {
        switch e := err.(type) {
        case sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAPIError:
            fmt.Printf("%v", e.EndpointError)
            // type cast to the specific error and access the field you want.
            settingsError := err.(sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAPIError)
            fmt.Println(settingsError.EndpointError.SharedLinkAlreadyExists.Metadata.Url)
        default:
            return err
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in the comments by @jimb. The answer is you access the fields like any other golang data structure - nothing special.

The errors I got when trying to access the fields were because the fields were not there.

The problem with the code was dependency issues. The code depends on an older version of the go-sdk and I referenced the latest version.

This question serves as a good explanation for how real golang programmers handle errors in their code with examples. I wasn't able to find this online, so I won't close the question.